# Using Lagrange multipliers to solve the following system of equations; getting imaginary numbers

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

Using Lagrange multipliers, solve the system of equations:

1. $2x=\lambda(8x)+2\mu$
2. $2y=\lambda(8y)$
3. $2z=\lambda(-2z)+4\mu$

with constraints:

$4x^2+4y^2-z^2=0$ and $2x+4z=7$

So solving for $\lambda$ in (2), I get $\lambda=\frac{1}4$, and continuing I get $\mu=0, z=0, x=\frac{7}2$ but for $y$ I get an imaginary number. Am I doing something wrong here? I am sure that the equations and constraints are correct.

Comment: How would I get $y=0$ from the equations?

Comment: Equation $(2)$ gives $y=0$ **OR** $\lambda=\frac14$. You seem to assume the latter.

Comment: Using $y=0$ I seem to have trouble solving for $\mu$ and $\lambda$

Comment: Well the constraints force two pairs of solutions for $(x,y,z)$ using $y=0$. Knowing $(x,y,z)$ gives a system to solve for $(\mu,\lambda)$.